# USB PAM login with SD Card

Tags: 12.04, login, security, sd-card, pam

I am trying to set up a PAM login token.  I want to use an SD card instead of a normal USB flash disk.

When I run the `pamusb-conf` to set up a new device, with the SD card inserted, it says that `there is no device detected`.  The SD card reader works fine in other respects (able to access through the GUI and through `/media` in terminal).  I run `pamusb-conf` in verbose mode and just get the following:

```
$ sudo pamusb-conf --verbose --add-device sdauth
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda
    Invalid: Not a removable device
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sr0
    Invalid: Device does not contain any volume
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/mmcblk0
    Invalid: Not a removable device
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/dm_2d0
    Invalid: Not a removable device
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda1
    Invalid: Not a removable device
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda2
    Invalid: Not a removable device
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/mmcblk0p1
    Invalid: Not a removable device
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda5
    Invalid: Not a removable device
Inspecting /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdb
    Invalid: Device does not contain any volume
No devices detected. Try running in verbose (-v) mode to see what's going on.
```

`pamusb-conf` works fine with a normal USB pendrive.

How can I make it so that I can use an SD card for pamusb?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:garhuy/pamusb
>   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libpam-usb pamusb-common pamusb-tools

This is patched pamusb by garhuy "https://launchpad.net/~garhuy/+archive/pamusb" which enables sdcard support.

I know its been 7 months after you posted it but it appears very high in google so it might be very handy for someone looking for it.

Comment: the ppa is throwing 404 error on update.